# Android: is it possible to show the action bar but don't show the Navigation bar in an app

Tags: android

i am new to android, my question is pretty much the one in the header. I develop for API Level 14 (Android 4.0). Do you know if it is possible to show Tabs in the actionbar but don't show the navigationbar (I mean the bar at the bottom with back, home,...)? If yes, could you tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your target is API Level 14+, please refer to the following official guidelines:

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html